# xcode-select cannot locate clang, even after installing command line tools

Tags: xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

When I try to run the `clang` command, I get the following error:

```
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'clang', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

And then I receive this pop-up:

[image: clang installation popup]

However, no matter how many times I click "Install" - going through a 15-minute install process - I continue to get the same error.

I have also tried running `xcode-select --install` however that gives the following error:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

I have also tried manually installing from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/).

I'm on an M1 mac running macOS Monterey Version 12.5.

It also yields a core dump:

```
2022-09-19 10:51:04.669 xcodebuild[1541:17443] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator', NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDESimulatorAvailability” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0000): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'
2022-09-19 10:51:04.688 xcodebuild[1541:17443] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21303/DVTFoundation/PlugInArchitecture/DataModel/DVTPlugIn.m:374
Details:  Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin)
Please ensure Xcode packages are up-to-date — try running 'xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch'.

NSBundle error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator', NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDESimulatorAvailability” couldn’t be loaded.}
Object:   <DVTPlugIn: 0x60000080b7a0>
Method:   -loadAssertingOnError:error:
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x600002c402c0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:

Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010653d410
  1  0x000000010653caec
  2  0x000000010653cc6c
  3  0x00000001063eb2ac
  4  0x00000001063b1118
  5  0x00000001063af528
  6  0x0000000181aa01b4
  7  0x0000000181aaf414
  8  0x000000010658158c
  9  0x000000010655d4b0
 10  0x00000001063af3c0
 11  0x00000001063af5e0
 12  0x00000001074372ec
 13  0x0000000107436ae0
 14  0x00000001074361e8
 15  0x0000000104c70324
 16  0x0000000104c21e0c
sh: line 1:  1543 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find clang 2> /dev/null
clang: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find clang 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 34304: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
```

How can I install clang?

Comment: This cured the situation for me! Started happening since updating to Monterey 12.6

Answer (score 123):

Please ensure Xcode packages are up-to-date — try running `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`.

This worked for me.

Comment: FWIW, this solved my problem for git (for Android Studio) git integration

Comment: Thank you so much. Then, what means this command?

Comment: For those who are wondering where the command came from, actually it is mentioned in the error message. Check and see line #10 of the original poster's "core dump" message.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and updated Xcode, relinked paths etc, which didn't help.

What worked was opening Xcode after the update and accepting the prompt to load essential development tools (for macOS and iOS).

A bit hidden in the error message is also the CLI solution: "Please ensure Xcode packages are up-to-date — try running '`xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`'."

Answer (score 4):

After installing XCode 14.1 on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1, my `clang` didn't work with an error very similar to this, and repeatedly tried to install the XCode command line tools. It turns out that `xcode-select` was pointing to the command line tools that are part of the full XCode package, and failing to find `clang` in there. `clang` is included in the command line tools package, but not in some versions of the full XCode package.

What I did to fix it was:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

This switches the location that `clang` and other tools are run from. If you want to switch back to running them from the XCode package, you can use:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: This solved it for me at first, but I had to use `xcrul altool` and the error occurred again.

Searching better, I remembered that I had changed the SDKROOT value in my `.zshrc` (it could also be in `.bash`).

Before:
`export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk`

After:
`export SDKROOT=/<SAME_PATH>/MacOSX13.1.sdk`

To confirm the version, just follow the same path.

I also needed to run it back from the XCode package

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Answer (score 2):

You can also open Xcode, select the default runtime tools (MacOS and iOS in my case), then clang should run as normal.

I believe this is the same as doing @LanderTome's answer, but not able to verify.